# Can I relocate the manipulator in Blender 2.79?

Tags: 3d-manipulator

I would like to be able to move the 3d Manipulator, in edit mode, so I can manipulate a vertex/vertices, edge or face about another location.

[image]

In the gif I select a vertex, I then move/relocate the 3D manipulator to another vertex (though it could just as easily be an edge or somewhere on a face) and, using the 3D manipulator, I move the location of the selected vertex. I then move the 3D manipulator again and repeat the process. There are many reasons I usually do this, the example shown here is just one reason.

[image]

How can I accomplish this in Blender 2.79?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Micro Manage Manipulator](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52049/how-to-micro-manage-manipulator)

Comment: Blender uses the term Origin Point instead of Center Point. You should be able to find lots of questions and answers on this site https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/origin and find options by tapping "space" in Blender typing in "origin"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to move the 3D manipulator widget itself](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16537/how-to-move-the-3d-manipulator-widget-itself)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the 3D Cursor will help get similar behavior to what you show in your question.

- Select the vertex/edge/face you want the operation to reference
- Press  <kbd>Shift</kbd>  +  <kbd>S</kbd>  to get the 3D cursor menu and choose **Cursor to Selected**
- In the viewport header open the pivot center drop-down and choose **3D cursor**
- Set your manipulator to **Scale** in the viewport header as well
- Select the vertex you want to move, click on the axis you want to constrain, slide the manipulator then change the value displayed in the tool bar to **0**. repeat again for the other axis.

[Here is a video of the procedure.](https://youtu.be/w5NpqLUXLyo)

It is also easier to perform this if you use shortcuts:

- Select the vertext you want to align to.
- Set the 3D cursor to it.
- press  <kbd>period</kbd>  and set the pivot point to 3D cursor
- press  <kbd>S</kbd>  then  <kbd>Y</kbd>  the  <kbd>0</kbd>  to align the vertext to the Y-Axis.
- press  <kbd>S</kbd>  then  <kbd>Z</kbd>  then  <kbd>0</kbd>  to align the vertext to the Z-Axis.

Answer (score 2):

The dot (normally in the centre of your primitive object is your origin point. (Picture 1 and picture 5)

The red and white crosshairs cursor in your viewport is your 3D cursor.

Individual vertices can be moved to the 3D cursor in edit mode OR the 3D cursor be snapped to a single vertex or median point between selected vertices or faces or edges using the shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>. There are various different options for interaction between mesh objects and the 3D cursor.

To place the 3D cursor to the centre of the viewport, press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. This will also centre your view.

The origin point can be changed in the Toolbar (<kbd>T</kbd>) where it says Origin. (Image 5)

The way a mesh translates or rotates or scales can be changed to use the origin point or the 3D cursor. The is very very useful. You can change these settings with the options at the bottom of your viewport. (Image 6)

If you would like your 3D cursor to sit on top of faces when you click on a mesh, you might find switching on Cursor Depth quite useful. This option can be found in the User preferences in the interface section. (Image 7)

the precise location of your 3D cursor can also be changed manually in the properties tab "N" if you scroll down. It's about halfway down or less.

[image]

Here is how the manipulator can be moved around in the viewport using the 3D cursor. The images go in order from left to right and top to bottom.

[image]

One other thing to note: When using proportional editing, scrolling the mouse wheel increases or decreases the area of influence. you'll see a circle getting bigger or smaller as you scroll up or down. Using shift and scrolling allows you to increase or decrease the influence much more accurately.

To place the 3D manipulator to the centre of 3D space, (0,0,0 in global coordinates), in Edit mode, press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to move the 3D cursor to the centre of 3D global space. Change the pivot point to be the 3D cursor (image 2 in the first diagram or the 3rd image in the second diagram).

The 3D manipulator will share the same place as the 3D cursor. If you want to make that permanent in Object mode, open the Tool Tab (Hotkey <kbd>T</kbd>) and click on the drop down menu which says "Origin". Set the "Origin to 3D cursor" in that menu. This menu also has a hotkey (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>).

Perhaps this is what you were wanting to know. Let me know if this doesn't exactly answer your question.

Comment: Rob, I did do that. I couldn't make blender do what I was trying to do. I'm sure its just a matter of being new to the software. The other questions that were asked did not cover what I am trying to do, at least not that I saw. Thank you though for the link, there where some questions included there that I did not see.

Comment: Perhaps you could upload it to google drives or if it's not many frames, convert the video into a simple gif in say GIMP. I think I know what you mean now but again, I'm not 100% sure. I'll try editing my answer to see if that helps at all.

Comment: Try this, this is a link to my Dropbox public folder. [link] (https://www.dropbox.com/s/0gah28s7hjx9fu9/Relocate%20Manipulator.mp4?dl=0)

Comment: I think you can attach gifs as images in the toolbar at the top of the message box as you write your question. Perhaps editing your question is the key there although I've never personally attached gif picture files before. I don't believe it's possible in comments though. Anyway, I updated my answer, so I hope that clears it up a bit more and gets to the heart of what you wanted to know.