# How do I move the 2D cursor in Blender?

Tags: animation, 2d

I am using Blender 2.82 for this.

To put it simply I am trying to move the cursor to a specific part of a pic I wanted. However I just can't seem to do it in a 2D animated project. I tried the cursor tool, the select box, I tried the move tool and holding things like Alt, Ctrl, and Shift to move the cursor but no luck. I even tried using the UV editor to move it but still nothing.

Note: I am selecting multiple strokes for this.

[image]

Comment: Duplicate of [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16537/how-to-move-the-3d-manipulator-widget-itself/16538?r=SearchResults#16538) (but the answer there doesn't explain how to do it for 2.8).

Comment: What do you mean by 2D cursor ?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand right, you want to rotate around selected point.
You can either move *Origin point* or the *3D cursor*.

**Moving Origin Point**

1. Enable *Transform Origins Only* in *Sidebar > Tool > Options*
2. Move the object's origin to desired location

[image]

**Moving 3D cursor**

1. Position the 3D cursor using the 3D cursor tool.
2. Switch Pivot point to > 3D Cursor

[image]

Comment: or Shift right-click.